# Babelnet categories

Tags: api, rest, categories

I'm trying to retrieve all the synsets categories of a given word in Babelnet via RESTful API.

E.G.
If you go to http://babelnet.org and search for *Java* you can see 17 results beloging to 7 categories (*Game and videogames*, *Drink and beverage*, *Information Technology* and so on).

How can I get the category of each synSet via API?
In the [API list](http://babelnet.org/guide) there is no reference to the categories..

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all synset's categories using the `getCategories()` method.

```
BabelSynset by = bn.getSynset(new BabelSynsetID("bn:03083790n"));

List<BabelCategory> cats = by.getCategories();
```